# Issue with while loop not printing correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question (please ignore #4)

[image: The question (please ignore #4)]

This is my code, i need it to print 3, 7, and 19 i believe

```py
i = 2
count = 0
print("Every 3rd sequential odd numbers between 2 and 19(inclusive):")
while i <= 19:
    if i%2 != 0:
        count += 1
    if count%3 == 0:
        print(i)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! "Believing" what this is supposed to do is not good enough. Please clarify what this should be doing first of all.

Comment: @sarema sorry,  Using a while loop: loop over every sequential odd number between 2 and 19 (inclusive); in the same while loop print only every 3rd sequential of those odd numbers you have encountered in the loop. My code is printing all numbers between 2 and 19

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] along with the expected and actual output. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You don't want `i += 1` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: And you also want the second `if` statement inside the first `if` statement.  Otherwise you'll print out an odd number and the following even number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's the solution for your problem, it prints out 7, 13 and 19 - every 3rd sequential odd numbers between 2 and 19:

```
i = 2
count = 0
print("Every 3rd sequential odd numbers between 2 and 19(inclusive):")
while i <= 19:
    if i%2 != 0:
        count += 1
        if count == 3:
            print(i)
            count=0
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 2
count = 0
print("Every 3rd sequential odd numbers between 2 and 19(inclusive):")
while i <= 19:
    if i%2 != 0:
        count += 1

        if count%3 == 0:
           print(i)

    i += 1
```

1. i += 1 should be outside the if statement.
2. Second if should be inside the first if.

Comment: Thank you very much